# Making javascript's Replace() match multiple words

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I want to strip the following out of a string:

- http://
- https://
- www.
- www2.
- /

An example string would be 'http://www.google.com', and I need to strip both 'http://' and 'www..'

I am trying to do this via Javascript's replace() using regex:

```
string.replace(/http:\/\/|www\.|www2\.|\//i,"");
```

The problem I'm encountering is that it will only strip one match from the regex. For example, in the above string only 'http://' would be removed.

Have I got the regex wrong or is replace only able to match once? I tested my expression on an online, non-JS regex builder and it worked fine.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//Add the /g tag at the end for "global"
string.replace(/http:(s?)|www(2?)|\//ig,"");
```